# Do I need a university affiliation to conduct and publish research?

Tags: publications, education

I earned a master's degree in education from a respected US university about ten years ago.  I completed a simple study with human subjects for my thesis.  It was approved and well-received by my advisor but not something that I pursued any publication on.  (If it matters, I'm a US citizen and I teach in the US).

I've been actively employed teaching since then, but have not entered the research sphere.  I have an idea for a research study I'd like to conduct at my school (where I teach).  Assuming I follow all the proper procedures re: permission for working with young subjects, approval from my supervisor, approval from my schools version of an institutional review board, and so on...

What hurdles will I face trying to get the completed study published without a university affiliation?

Comment: Teaching in a secondary school?

Comment: My education level is different than the suggested duplicate.  Unlike an undergrad, I have completed research studies, albeit at the masters and not the phd level.  I consider this enough of a difference whereas many of the comments instruct the OP to learn how to write academically.

Comment: Teaching in a primary school, @Azor Ahai

Comment: @nuggethead The accepted answer covers this one

Comment: @Azor Ahai I'm interested to learn what hurdles I'll face, not whether it's necessary

Comment: I think that question still covers that.

Comment: One hurdle that I can think of is determining whether the study is of sufficient interest to merit publication, since I assume the usual filters such as grant application acceptance, colleague advice, experience in the field for what is publishable, etc. are not applicable in your case. If this is based on your Masters work (you don't say whether it is, or whether this is a new research effort), then maybe it's passed some filters, but keep in mind that Masters level work is often quite distant from professional level work.

Comment: The main problems are 1) identifying if the piece of work is really of interest, new, not covered. But you might know that 2) if the review isn't double blind, whatever generates doubt or is not understandable to the referee will be likely judged wrong. I give you an extreme example: if there is a debate on quantum here on Physics SE, two different takes might appear equally clear (read equally obscure) to me, and I will rely somehow on the users reputation. Bring affiliated gives some reputation. It is not a malevolent attitude, it originates by reasonable implicit consideration.